# How to read vertices from vertex buffer in Direct3d11

Tags: directx, buffer, direct3d, vertex

I have a question regarding vertex buffers. How does one read the vertices from the vertex buffer in D3D11? I want to get a particular vertex's position for calculations, if this approach is wrong, how would one do it? The following code does not (obviously) work.

```
VERTEX* vert;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
devcon->Map(pVBufferSphere, NULL, D3D11_MAP_READ, NULL, &ms);
vert = (VERTEX*) ms.pData;
devcon->Unmap(pVBufferSphere, NULL);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**Where your code is wrong:**

- You asking GPU to give you an address to its memory(`Map()`),
- Storing this adress (`operator=()`),
- Then saying: "Thanks, I don't need it anymore" (`Unmap()`).

After unmap, you can't really say where your pointer now points. It can point to memory location where already allocated another stuff or at memory of your girlfriend's laptop (just kidding =) ).
You must copy data (all or it's part), not pointer in between `Map()` `Unmap()`: use memcopy, `for` loop, anything. Put it in array, `std::vector`, BST, everything.

**Typical mistakes that newcomers can made here:**

1. Not to check `HRESULT` return value  from [`ID3D11DeviceContext::Map`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. If map fails it can return whatever pointer it likes. Dereferencing such pointer leads to undefined behavior. So, better check any DirectX function return value.
2. Not to check D3D11 debug output. It can clearly say what's wrong and what to do in plain good English language (clearly better than my English =) ). So, you can fix bug almost instantly.
3. You can only read from [ID3D11Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if it was [created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) CPU access flag which means that you must also set [`D3D11_USAGE_STAGING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) usage fag.

**How do we usualy read from buffer:**

- We don't use staging buffers for rendering/calculations: it's slow.
- Instead we copy from main buffer (non-staging and non-readable by CPU) to staging one ([`ID3D11DeviceContext::CopyResource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and then copying data to system memory (`memcopy()`).
- We don't do this too much in release builds, it will harm performance.
- There are two main real-life usages of staging buffers: debugging (see if buffer contains wrong data and fix some bug in algorithm) and reading final non-pixel data (for example if you calculating scientific data in Compute shader).
- In most cases you can avoid staging buffers at all by well-designing your code. Think as if CPU<->GPU was connected only one way: CPU->GPU.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As a newbie in directx in didn't realize I could just multiply the final transform matrix with a vertex to get its position in c++ code, i.e. outside the shader. That's all I wanted so using an output stream from the pipeline was a severe overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The following code only get the address of the mapped resource, you didn't read anything before Unmap.

```
vert = (VERTEX*) ms.pData;
```

If you want to read data from the mapped resource, first allocate enough memory, then use memcpy to copy the data, I don't know your VERTEX structure, so I suppose vert is void*, you can convert it yourself

```
vert = new BYTE[ms.DepthPitch];
memcpy(vert, ms.pData, ms.DepthPitch];
```

Comment: After copying memory, how do you actually gain access to the vertices?

Answer (score 2):

Drop's answer was helpful. I figured that the reason why I wasn't able to read the buffer was because I didn't have the CPU_ACCESS_FLAG set to D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ before. Here

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(bufferDesc));
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = iNumElements * sizeof(T);
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ | D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE ;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
bufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(T);
```

And then to read data I did

```
    const ID3D11Device& device = *DXUTGetD3D11Device();
    ID3D11DeviceContext& deviceContext = *DXUTGetD3D11DeviceContext();
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    HRESULT hr = deviceContext.Map(g_pParticles, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &ms);    

    Particle* p = (Particle*)malloc(sizeof(Particle*) * g_iNumParticles);
    ZeroMemory(p, sizeof(Particle*) * g_iNumParticles);
    memccpy(p, ms.pData, 0, sizeof(ms.pData));
    deviceContext.Unmap(g_pParticles, 0);

    delete[] p;
```

I agree it's a performance decline, I wanted to do this, just to be able to debug the values!

Thanks anyway! =)