# Byte Array Initialization Causes DirectX to Crash

Tags: c++, directx-11

So I'm trying to gain access to vertex buffers on the GPU. Specifically I need to do some calculations with the vertices. So in order to do that I attempt to map the resource (vertex buffer) from the GPU, and copy it into system memory so the CPU can access the vertices. I used the following SO thread to put the code together: [How to read vertices from vertex buffer in Direct3d11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17414491/how-to-read-vertices-from-vertex-buffer-in-direct3d11)

Here is my code:

```
HRESULT hr = pSwapchain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (void**)&pDevice);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return false;

pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&pContext);
pContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &pRenderTargetView, nullptr);

//Vertex Buffer
ID3D11Buffer* veBuffer;
UINT Stride;
UINT veBufferOffset;

pContext->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &veBuffer, &Stride, &veBufferOffset);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapped_rsrc;
pContext->Map(veBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_READ, NULL, &mapped_rsrc);
void* vert = new BYTE[mapped_rsrc.DepthPitch];     //DirectX crashes on this line...
memcpy(vert, mapped_rsrc.pData, mapped_rsrc.DepthPitch);
pContext->Unmap(veBuffer, 0);
```

I'm somewhat of a newbie when it comes to C++. So my assumptions may be incorrect. The initialization value that

```
mapped_rsrc.DepthPitch
```

returns is quite large. It returns 343597386. According to the documentation I listed below, it states that the return value of DepthPitch is returned in bytes. If I replace the initialization value with a much smaller number, like 10, the code runs just fine. From what I read about the Map() function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_mapped_subresource

It states :

> Note  The runtime might assign values to RowPitch and DepthPitch that
> are larger than anticipated because there might be padding between
> rows and depth.

Could this have something to do with the large value that is being returned? If so, does that mean I have  to parse DepthPitch to remove any unneeded data? Or maybe it is an issue with the way vert is initialized?

Comment: You must test all functions that return ``HRESULT`` for failure with ``FAILED`` or ``SUCCEEDED`` macros. The ``Map`` call is clearly failing likely because that resource cannot be mapped. You don't show the creation of ``veBuffer``

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn Ok, I will try doing that. As far as veBuffer goes, the most I've done with defining it is what I have above: `ID3D11Buffer* veBuffer;` I did read in the SO link I posted about using Staging Buffers and CopyResource() to read from the GPU as well. Not sure if I need that here or not? I guess I'll just focus on one issue at a time though.

Comment: OK, so you never created the vertex buffer.... That's the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no Vertex Buffer bound, so your `IAGetVertexBuffers` failed to return anything. You have to create a VB.

See [Microsoft Docs: How to Create a Vertex Buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-buffers-vertex-how-to)

> As someone new to DirectX 11, you should take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).